# How to set async/await count in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, threadpoolexecutor

I am having a node js server which reads input from the html page, and depending on the input it will invoke one of the functions. One such function is createUser, in create user i am calling an invoke function, the code snippet for this is as follows:

```
app.post('/createUser',async function(req,res, next)
{
    try{
        var id= req.body.id;
        var date= req.body.date;
        var args= [];
        args.push(id);
        args.push(date);
        req.setTimeout(2400000);
        const result= await invoke(options["org1"],args,requests[ "createUser" ])
        res.send("Chaincode invoked");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        res.send(e.toString());
    }
});
```

Say there are 1000 queries firing simultaneously to this invoke function, which is asynchronous, is there a way to control on the number of times this async call to be executed irrespective of input(for example, if user fires 1000 queries simultaneously, can invoke function could be called only for 128 queries simultaneously and repeat for all the input).
Something like Executor Service in java.

Comment: Do you use any db? If so, which driver so you use for node? You cant handle it from node side if your driver doesnt allow you it.

Comment: Same as anywhere else. Count the calls. Rate limiting algorithms are universal. Also, app server doesn't look like an efficient place to do this. Could be handled at request (Varnish?)